# Replace one string with the content pulled from other file

Tags: bash

I have an TARGET.md file, I'm looking for a string and I want to replace it with the content of other `md` file, I have tried many combinations but it seems like the newline in the files are the ones `sed` is not liking, I just need to do this using pure bash(it doesn't have to be `sed`) because this is how the whole script is running:

This works:

```sh
    local search="##### Header"
    local replace="##### Header\\
\\
Line 1\\
Line 2\\
Line 3\\
Line 4"
    sed -i '' -e "s/${search}/${replace}/" TARGET.md
```

But this won't:

**file1.md content:**

```
##### Header

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

**Script:**

```
    local search="##### Header"
    local replace=$(curl "path/to/file/in/other/place/file1.md")
    sed -i '' -e "s/${search}/${replace}/" TARGET.md
```

**NOTE:**  I don't have the `file1.md` in the same place, I'm doing a curl to get the raw content from it, this is why the replace is in a variable.

I'm assuming the concept is possible but my sed syntax is wrong knowing sed can handle newlines out of the box, but not sure what is the proper way to do this.

I've been searching for some days now, any help, tip or guide is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show sample `TARGET.md`

Comment: @anubhava, `TARGET.md` is very simple:
`##### Header

- Test content
`

Comment: @oguzismail that I don't actually have the `file1.md` in the same place, I'm doing a curl to get the raw content

Comment: I realized that when I saw the answer, just updated the question, thanks for the comment @oguzismail

Comment: please update the question with the expected result of the `sed` command; please update the question with more details of your current issue, eg, what does "this won't" mean? did you get an error? did you get the wrong results? after running `replace=$(curl...)`, show us what's in `replace`, eg, `typeset -p replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking `TARGET.md` file from David's answer:

```sh
cat TARGET.md

##### Unreleased

my dog
has fleas
```

You can run `sed` with `r` command like this:

```sh
search="##### Unreleased"
sed -e "/$search/{r file1.md" -e ';d;}' TARGET.md

##### Header

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

my dog
has fleas
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tool. `sed` is a line editor at heart. While you can repeatedly append to pattern space in some instances, `awk` with `getline` provides a more flexible solution. For example with your `file1.md`:

```
##### Header

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

and your `TARGET.md` as:

```
##### Unreleased

my dog
has fleas
```

The to replace `"##### Unreleased"` with the content of `file1.md`, you can do:

```
awk -v replace="file1.md" -v search="##### Unreleased" '
    $0 == search {while (getline line < replace ) { print line }; next }
                 { print }
' TARGET.md
```

Above you have your `replace` and `search` as with `sed`, but instead of using the line-editor, you use `awk` to locate the line containing `search` and the read all lines from `replace using` getline`. The second rule just prints all other lines as is.

**Example Use/Output**

In the directory containing each file, you can simply select-copy the above and middle-mouse paste into the terminal to test:

```
$ awk -v replace="file1.md" -v search="##### Unreleased" '
>     $0 == search {while (getline line < replace ) { print line }; next }
>                  { print }
> ' TARGET.md
##### Header

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

my dog
has fleas
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you @david-c-rankin, I failed to explain in my question that I don't actually have the file1.md in the same place, I'm doing a curl to get the raw content.

Comment: @RudyPalacios If you `curl`, be aware `curl` adds DOS line-endings to the file downloaded. In this case that won't matter, `awk` treats the carriage-return as whitepace when using the default field-separator, but if you make more changes or add other utilities, after you `curl`, you use `dos2unix file1.md` to convert the line-endings, or use `sed -i 's/\r/$/' file1.md`.